# inotifywait - Rename file using just filename, not full path?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, inotify

How do I use just the filename to rename files use this script syntax?

```
#!/bin/bash

WATCHED=/mnt/Watched
DESTINATION=/mnt/Destination

inotifywait -re CLOSE_WRITE,CREATE,MOVED_TO --format $'%e\t%w%f' -m $WATCHED |
    while IFS=$'\t' read -r events new
    do
        cp -r "$WATCHED/$new" "$DESTINATION/"
    done
```

When I run this I get this result

`cp: cannot stat '/mnt/Watched//mnt/Watched/newfile.mkv': No such file or directory`

I know that if the format was setup like this `--format %f` it would work fine but I cannot set it up that way as I need the events and full path for other parts of my script that I left out. So how do I pull out and assign just the filename for my cp command?

Thanks

Comment: Change `"$WATCHED/$new"` to `"$new"`

Comment: Yes that worked! I knew it had to be simple. Thanks!

Comment: If you have a solution, then post it as an answer explaining what the issue was and how the solution solves the issue. If the solution does not require an answer, then delete your question, as it couldn't have been important. I have rolled back your tagging in the title.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `"$WATCHED/$new"` to `"$new"` per jordanm's suggestion and it now works.